# How to clone a node and use it as documentElement for a new DOMDocument?

Tags: php, dom

In PHP5, I have a DOMDocument (`$xmlDoc1`). Let's say its documentElement is: `<root id="1" type=""/>`. I create a new DOMDocument `$xmlDoc2`.

What I need to do is clone `$xmlDoc1`'s documentElement (with its attributes but not its children), and use it as the documentElement for `$xmlDoc2`.

In ASP, you could write :

```
XMLDoc2.DocumentElement = XMLDoc1.DocumentElement.CloneNode(False)
```

PHP DOM has a `cloneNode()` method, but doesn't allow to append the cloned node to another document.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php

Example:

```
<?php
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXml('<root attr1="a" attr2="b"><foo></foo></root>');

$dom2 = new DomDocument();
$dom2->appendChild(
    $dom2->importNode($dom->documentElement->cloneNode(false), true) 
);

header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"');
echo $dom2->saveXml();
```

Executed:

http://codepad.org/yCFegZbp

Comment: Thanks, that's it (it had escaped my quick browsing of the docs). Not 100% solved, though: the attributes are not copied.

Comment: It works in your example, so I'll check my code. Thanks again.

Comment: See the updated example. It worked on my test machine, probably some php version thing.